# Why does ASP.NET Identity generate its own Guid for primary keys instead of relying on SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

As the title says, why does ASP.NET Identity generates a Guid and converts it to string then storing it as nvarchar(128) (or I maybe wrong with the datatype) to the AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles tables?

Why is it done this way instead of setting the primary key of the tables in SQL Server to type uniqueidentifier and using newid() or newsequentialid()?

Should I follow ASP.NET Identity's convention with regards to generating and storing Guids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there're many entities within the ASP.NET Identity domain which have a generic type parameter to specify the identifier type.

For example [`IUser<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613291(v=vs.108).aspx).

In the other hand, because of some ASP.NET Identity team design decision, they locked the `TKey` type to `string` in the `IUserStore<TUser>` interface. See its signature:

```
public interface IUserStore<TUser> : IUserStore<TUser, string>, IDisposable
       where TUser : class, IUser<string>
```

That is, any custom user store implementation must work with `string` user key. Also, it's not said that this interface should be implemented on top of a relational database. For example, in my case I've implemented it for [Redis](https://github.com/mfidemraizer/stackredis.aspnet.identity) and [Mongo](https://github.com/mfidemraizer/Mongo.AspNet.Identity). Also, I've implemented it for [HTTP](https://github.com/mfidemraizer/http.aspnet.identity) too!

In summary, the reason behind the scenes for which you are forced to store any identifier as `string` equivalent in your data store is because of the whole `IUser<TUser>` interface. Why they've locked the identifier type to `string` is tied to some design decision (in my case, I find it that they made a wrong decision...).

Comment: Perhaps they should have given developers a choice to simply change the type of the primary keys to maybe a uniqueidentifier or an int and not just a workaround just like in this link http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity. Oh well, I guess I have to stick with the string type since I really need to store the primary key as guid. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Kharlan I'm agree with you... anyway, you need to go with workarounds ;P

Comment: @Kharlan you can totally change `string` to `Guid`, but it'll take a bit more work